# Postgres service is not starting while implementing the streeming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

While I am trying to implement replication in PostgreSQL, I have created a `recovery.conf` in the standby machine, but when I am trying to start the postgres service in the standby machine the service is not starting. 
The error message is:

[image]

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL log files. By default they're in `%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.2\data\pg_log`; enter that into `Start->Run` . Time to plan an upgrade for the master too, 9.2 is ageing.

Comment: [Try this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53545/cannot-get-my-slave-replication-server-to-start) Follow these steps I think it will work